# CMS to use in creating a native android or ios app

Tags: android, ios, content-management-system

Help needed

I need to know what is the proper way to create a native android and IOS apps. Is it possible to use CMS' like Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla if not Is PHP compatible in building apps using framework CODEIGNITER?

My skills:
Client side:
HTML5 
CSS3 
Javascript

Server side:
PHP
Codeigniter framework - beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get started with building android apps here - http://developer.android.com/about/start.html

You can get started with iOS apps here - http://designthencode.com/scratch/

If you'd like to use those various web frameworks to work as your app - the actual app you'd write would consist of a simple web view on each respective system. You would just point it to your site on load. Designing your site UI to fit the phones would be the most important part, and you'd want to read up on responsive CSS. Making an "app" isn't entirely necessary though, you can design your site and test it out on the browser of each device, before writing the respective programs to have it open.

Comment: Thank you Ditmar! If I understand you correctly, the frontend is more important than the backend functionality? I have read on responsive design and I will continue reading more. I plan to have my native app on google play and app store to have it downloaded by multiple users.